# When I add an image to a project do I need to also add the @2x version?

Tags: ios, xcode

Do I need to add the @2x version to the project in Xcode or will it know to find the @2x version in the folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the @2x version of the image to the project in Xcode. Remember to check the "Copy items into destination group's folder" box when adding the image. Also check your targets in the "Add to targets" menu. Think about it this way, if you don't add it to the project in Xcode, how will the image be found when it is deployed to actual devices of customers? They can't (obviously) connect remotely to your computer and download the @2x image. When customers with retina displays use your app and you don't include the @2x image in the project, the low quality image will be displayed.

In summation, **YES**. You must include the @2x version of the image if you wish to use a higher resolution image on retina devices.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's quicker to just test it than to ask, but I don't think the image will be included in the bundle if you don't add it in Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be part of the project, but when using the image, xcode will automatically pick the right one when referencing it.